# Enviar e-mail de forma assíncrona asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um formulário que retorna *ActionResult* que envia um e-mail após concluir a operação.

Gostaria de deixar esse e-mail assíncrono, pois demora bastante as vezes, tentei colocar em uma *Task* usando o método *SendMailAsync* da classe *SmtpClient*, contudo não funciona.

Alguém saberia me dizer o que preciso fazer para enviar esses e-mails de forma assíncrona no asp.net mvc?

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
{
   var smtp = new SmtpClient();
   smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Só seguir o exemplo:

```
public async Task SendEmail(string toEmailAddress, string emailSubject, string emailMessage)
{
    var message = new MailMessage();
    message.To.Add(toEmailAddress);

    message.Subject = emailSubject;
    message.Body = emailMessage;

    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu já tenho uma classe genérica, meu problema é que não faz envio de forma assíncrona.

Comment: então coloque o método de envio de e-mail de maneira genérica na sua aplicação também, mude ele conforme a sua necessidade (provavelmente vai precisar mudar o model que eu criei) e chame em seu controller (ou na parte correta da sua aplicação) que vai funcionar

Comment: editei minha resposta pra ficar de uma maneira mais simplificada

Answer (score 0):

Tente com o seguinte código:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAcation()
{
    //Codigo de criacao do objeto message
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
       var smtp = new SmtpClient();
       smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
    });
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Funcionou assim Leonardo, será que sempre é entregue de forma correta? Ou pode ocorrer perdas? Talvez para segurança eu deveria criar uma fila de menssageria para processar as mensagens?

Comment: Eu uso o `Task.Factory.StartNew` em meus projetos para fazer esse tipo de envio de e-mail(enviar e não aguardar confirmação) quanto as perdas, eu nunca tive problemas, porém não sei te responder se podem ocorrer, **Acredito(não tenho certeza)** que só ocorra falha caso tenha uma exceção, você pode tentar salvar um log ou algo do gênero.

Answer (score 0):

você não precisa criar uma nova `Task` com o `Task.Run` ou o `Task.Factory.StartNew`, afinal o `smtp.SendMailAsync` já retorna uma `Task`.

Tudo o que você precisa fazer (ou melhor, não fazer), é não esperar pelo retorno dela, ou seja, não usar o `await`.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAcation()
{
    var smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
    return View();
}
```